# Adding nodes to multiple, stacked features

Tags: qgis

Am am working in QGIS on a dataset with multiple, overlapping polygons, often sharing borders. Sometimes I want to adjust a border, and need to add more nodes. Normally I would doubleclick a line to insert a node, but if I need to adjust multiple, stacked features, it would be nice to be able to do that for the whole stack. Is it possible to work on a number of stacked features simultaneously, and e.g. add a node to every “layer”?
[image]